# XNA 2D platformer world collision

Tags: c#, xna, collision

i´m having a little problem with my world collison in a platformer game i´m working on. I know why the (or I think I know) problem occours. My program seems to go into the first "if" when it´s not ment too. Something there is wrong (I think) but I can´t find what.

Secondly I wonder if my solution over all is an good idea or if a should go for something else. If so what´s wrong? I´m pretty beginner on programming so please be gentle with me ;D

```
    protected void CheckWorldCollison()
    {
        float collisionWidth = this.width + (Tile.GetTileSize() * 2);
        float collisionHeight = this.height + (Tile.GetTileSize() * 2);

        for (int x = -1; x < (collisionWidth / Tile.GetTileSize()) - 1; x++)
        {
            for (int y = -1; y < (collisionHeight / Tile.GetTileSize()) - 1; y++)
            {
                Vector2 tempTilePosition = new Vector2((int)(this.position.X / Tile.GetTileSize()) + x, (int)(this.position.Y / Tile.GetTileSize()) + y);

                if (tempTilePosition.X >= 0 && tempTilePosition.X < (Game1.testMap.GetWidth())
                    && tempTilePosition.Y >= 0 && tempTilePosition.Y < (Game1.testMap.GetHeight()))
                {
                    this.tilesToCheck.Add(Game1.testMap.GetTile(tempTilePosition));
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (Tile t in this.tilesToCheck)
        {
            t.setIsCkecked(true);

            if (t.GetTileType() != TileType.transparent)
            {
                Vector2 distance = this.position - t.GetPosition();

                //Console.WriteLine(distance);
                Console.WriteLine((distance + this.origin).X);

                if (((distance + this.origin).X >= 0 && (distance + this.origin).X <= Tile.GetTileSize())
                    || ((distance - this.origin).X >= 0 && (distance - this.origin).X <= Tile.GetTileSize()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine((distance + this.origin).Y);

                    if ((distance + this.origin).Y <= 0)
                    {
                        if (this.speed.Y > 0)
                        {
                            if ((distance + this.origin + this.speed).Y > 0)
                            {
                                this.position.Y = (t.GetPosition() - this.origin).Y;
                                this.speed.Y = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (((distance - this.origin).Y - Tile.GetTileSize()) <= 0)
                    {
                        if (this.speed.Y < 0)
                        {
                            if (((distance - this.origin + this.speed).Y - Tile.GetTileSize()) < 0)
                            {
                                this.position.Y = (t.GetPosition() + this.origin).Y + Tile.GetTileSize();
                                this.speed.Y = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (((distance + this.origin).Y >= 0 && (distance + this.origin).Y <= Tile.GetTileSize())
                    || ((distance - this.origin).Y >= 0 && (distance - this.origin).Y <= Tile.GetTileSize()))
                {
                    if ((distance + this.origin).X <= 0)
                    {
                        if (this.speed.X > 0)
                        {
                            if ((distance + this.origin + this.speed).X > 0)
                            {
                                this.position.X = (t.GetPosition() - this.origin).X;
                                this.speed.X = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (((distance - this.origin).X - Tile.GetTileSize()) >= 0)
                    {
                        if (this.speed.X < 0)
                        {
                            if (((distance - this.origin + this.speed).X - Tile.GetTileSize()) < 0)
                            {
                                this.position.X = (t.GetPosition() + this.origin).X + Tile.GetTileSize();
                                this.speed.X = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        this.tilesToCheck.Clear();
    }
```

Just wanna say that I guess that these questions pop up here like all the time, but I hadn´t written if I really didn´t need help.

Comment: Which is the first `if` exactly? One tip that will help you is to change the application type to a console application. That way when you run your game, you will also have a debugger window you can write to, (i.e `Console.WriteLine`) and see what values your objects hold.. (Also, draw your object bounding boxes :) )

Comment: Sorry i´m stuid as "(ugly word)" I meant the first one in the foreach loop that loops throw (spelling?) the tiles that surounds the entity. But I dont think that the problem lies there anymore. Maybe I also should have specified what the problems actually are. On walls that are more than one tile high you cant move. He gets stuck. And on alone tiles, when you have a negative Y-speed he "teleports" to the position I specify when he is touching a not solid tile from underneath

Comment: I'm sure you can imagine it is hard to diagnose the problem, but it sounds as though the problem would be that by correcting yourself out of one collision - you enter into a second one which then corrects you into ... You would be best to check where is a valid place to move from the collision before doing so